# jQuery fcbkselection

Tags: jquery-selectors

I am using this to select all items and check them

```
$("#selectAll").live('click', function() {
$("#fcbklist li .fcbklist_item:not(:has(:hidden:checked))").click();
});
```

That works.
and to uncheck

```
$("#unselectAll").live('click', function() {
$("#fcbklist li .fcbklist_item:not(has(:hidden:checked))").click();
});
```

the unselectAll code does not work. It behaves like a toggle. Those that are checked get unchecked and those unchecked get checked.

Please what is the proper way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was so simple. This creates a toggle

```
 $("#fcbklist li .fcbklist_item").click();
```